# can't connect remotely to ftp server

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, ufw

after installing and configuring vsftpd on my Ubuntu 20.04, I'm unable to connect to my ftp server remotely. It works fine inside my LAN.

I'm behind a NAT, but have all the necessary ports forwarded, even tried DMZ, but with the same results.

Here is the output of [netstat -tulpn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu4NW.png)

Here is my
[ufw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl0Cf.png)

and here is my vsftpd config file:

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
local_root=/home/ftp/
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=ftp
force_dot_files=YES
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
rsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=YES
force_local_data_ssl=NO
force_local_logins_ssl=NO
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
```

Comment: Arevyou connecting from an ipv6 enabled host?

Comment: No I'm not. Normally using ipv4.

Comment: I expect that you have a number of problems then, including nat anf because your config file implies to me that ftp is only lustening on iov6.  (first line of your config).  Are you behind NAT, and if so, how is your router configured and what are the first 2 octets of your WAN IP?

Comment: I'm behind NAT, but the port is port-forwarded on my router. First two octets are 89.176. and on vsftpd I've changed it as you suggested, so `listen=YES` and `listen_ipv6=NO`, but still have the same problem.

Comment: What is port-forwarded on your router?  FTP is a horrid protocol and requires more then just port 21 to work.  Indeed, as an early debugging step, I'd set that box up as the target of the DMZ so all ports are forwarded to it - once you have FTP working with the DMZ you can work out what ports need to be forwarded.  (this somewhat depends on how FTP is set up)

Comment: (You might need to reduce the pasv_max_port to something closer to 40010 and then map all the pasv ports across).

Comment: FTP didn't work even with DMZ on, so I suspect the fault on the server side. Also here are my port-forwarded [ports](https://imgur.com/a/0CUZAsg)

Comment: @Zajdacak please edit your question with additional information instead of adding it as a comment as comments could get removed. You might want to add the output of `netstat -tulpn`